# Showing renames in hg status?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, rename

I know that Mercurial can track renames of files, but how do I get it to *show* me renames instead of adds/removes when I do `hg status`? For instance, instead of:

```
A bin/extract-csv-column.pl
A bin/find-mirna-binding.pl
A bin/xls2csv-separate-sheets.pl
A lib/Text/CSV/Euclid.pm
R src/extract-csv-column.pl
R src/find-mirna-binding.pl
R src/modules/Text/CSV/Euclid.pm
R src/xls2csv-separate-sheets.pl
```

I want some indication that four files have been moved.

I think I read somewhere that the output is like this to preserve backward-compatibility with something-or-other, but I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Do you mean "hg status"? I don't think hg log produces output in the format that you've listed.

Comment: Actually, I'm using the following to make hg log show extra stuff (and colors): http://bitbucket.org/sjl/mercurial-cli-templates/src/ So let's change the question to `hg status`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

Before you commit, you can use `hg diff --git` to show what was renamed:

```
$ hg diff --git
diff --git a/theTest.txt b/aTest.txt
rename from theTest.txt
rename to aTest.txt
```

Note that this only works if you used `hg mv`, `hg rename`, or `mv` and `hg addremove --similarity 100`.

After you commit, you can still use `hg diff`, but you'll have to specify the change using `-r`:

```
$ hg diff -r 0 -r 1 --git
diff --git a/test.txt b/theTest.txt
rename from test.txt
rename to theTest.txt
```

For both `hg status` and `hg log`, use the -C command-line flag to see the source that a file was copied from.

```
$ hg status -C
A aTest.txt
  theTest.txt
R theTest.txt
```

The line just below aTest.txt indicates the source it was copied from (theTest.txt).

```
$ hg log -v -C
changeset:   1:4d7b42489d9f
tag:         tip
user:        jhurne
date:        Tue Apr 20 20:57:07 2010 -0400
files:       test.txt theTest.txt
copies:      theTest.txt (test.txt)
description:
Renamed test.txt
```

You can see the files that were affected (test.txt and theTest.txt), and that "theTest.txt" was copied from test.txt.

Answer (score 18):

You can find out how many files have been renamed with hg summary.  If you want to see the actual files that were renamed, the fastest way I've found is to do:

```
hg st -a -C
```

This will output something like this:

```
A <path\to\renamed\file>
  <path\copied\from>
A <path\to\added\file>
A <path\to\renamed\file>
  <path\copied\from>
```

Since hg status considers a rename to be a copy and a remove, your renamed files will list a copied from file.  Files that were added but not renamed will not list a copied from file.