# How to distinguish between added and renamed files in Hg hook

Tags: python, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

There is [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2679488/674976) on how to achieve this in CLI. I am interested in how to do it in the hook function.

My function currently is defined as

```
def check_committed_files(ui, repo, **kwargs)
```

With `repo.status()` I can see all files in the changeset. However for a renamed file it shows this:

> `<status modified=[], added=['new_name.stp'], removed=['old_name.stp'], deleted=[], unknown=[], ignored=[], clean=[]>Checking files...`

This doesn't distinguish renamed files. Especially in case of multiple renames, it becomes hard to detect them based on this. How can I do it?